# Bash - Set Azure Variable From Bash Var or AZ Command

Tags: bash, azure, variables

I can't set a variable to anything other than a raw value. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) ([and another set](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)) don't really help with this.

Context of how the variable is defined:

```
    jobs:
      - job: "Do things"
        variables:
          STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME: ''
        steps:
          - script: #do stuff here
```

This works fine:
`echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME]bob'`

However, if I run the code below, `STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME` is null:

```
name_of_storage_account_to_release_to=$(az resource list --tag is_live=false --query [0].name --out tsv)
echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME]$name_of_storage_account_to_release_to'
```

This also fails:

```
echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME]$(az resource list --tag is_live=false --query [0].name --out tsv)'
```

Looks like it should be the simplest thing possible, but I can't figure out the syntax. Note that I am sure my fetching commands work, because I can echo the result of:

`name_of_storage_account_to_release_to=$(az resource list --tag is_live=false --query [0].name --out tsv)`

and it works just fine. It's setting Azure variable that's the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to use double quote which allows variable expansion : `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME]$name_of_storage_account_to_release_to"`

Comment: No, I haven't, my first time using bash, I really hope it was that simple and I was just missing something obvious. Thank you. Trying now. Have to step away for an hour and half, will update results.

Comment: Yea, that was it. I guess I don't know Bash. Thanks a ton, you literally saved me hours. Thought I skimmed the docs enough.

Comment: @VSO Please post what worked for you as an answer below so it helps others in the community as well.

Comment: @Philippe Want to post that as an answer really quick since you answered the question? If not, I will later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double quote which allows variable expansion :

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME]$name_of_storage_account_to_release_to"
```